# Block Blank HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR traffic

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to block traffic when `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is blank/empty from `htaccess`?

I've tried these two:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} ^.{0}$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```